# Click screenshot of part of the screen using python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

At the moment the below code shows a camera layout using laptop webcam just fine - I want to show a rectangle frame within the camera window - user will hold a book aligned to the frame and I need to capture an image of the book i.e capture image of the part within the frame. I am struggling to

1. Show a transparent rectangle as a frame (this is inside a boxlayout inside a camera floatlayout)
2. Grab an image of only the part within the frame

There is a button below the camera layout at click of which the image will be saved to a folder on the machine
Please can somebody guide me how to proceed and whether this can be achieved in any other way using any other module

```
import kivy
from PIL import ImageGrab
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from numpy import shape

kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle



class CamApp(App):
# Function to take a screenshot
def screengrab(self, *largs):
    im2 = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)
    im2.show()
    #outname = self.fileprefix + '_%(counter)04d.png'
    #Window.screenshot(name=outname)



def build(self):
    # create a floating layout as base
    camlayout = FloatLayout(size=(600, 600))
    cam = Camera()  # Get the camera
    cam = Camera(resolution=(1024, 1024), size=(300, 300))
    cam.play = True  # Start the camera
    camlayout.add_widget(cam)
    boxlayout = BoxLayout(id='imageBox', size_hint=[0.5, 0.7], pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
    boxlayout.bind(size=self.update_rect, pos=self.update_rect)
    with boxlayout.canvas.before:
        #Color(0, 1, 0, 1)  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
        self.rect = Rectangle(size=boxlayout.size,
                              pos=boxlayout.pos, outline='black')

    camlayout.add_widget(boxlayout)

    button = Button(text='Take Picture', size_hint=(0.12, 0.12))
    button.bind(on_press=self.screengrab)
    camlayout.add_widget(button)  # Add button to Camera Layout

    self.fileprefix = 'snap'

    return camlayout
def update_rect(self,instance, value):
    self.rect.pos = instance.pos
    self.rect.size = instance.size
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

[Click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Dhf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In kivy, the Color() function takes arguments representing RGBA.  That means the last argument is alpha, and passing it a float will make it transparent.
So while `Color(0, 1, 0, 1)` is a solid color, `Color(0, 1, 0, .5)` will be semitransparent.

As for grabbing an image of only part of the frame, you might consider grabbing the whole frame, then using PIL to crop the image with

```
from PIL import Image 

im = Image.open(r"C:\path\to\picture\my_screenshot.png") 
im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```

Just replace left, top, right, and bottom with the dimensions you want to cut out.